# Trying to Insert records into table Error on FK T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to insert new text book records into a a database. I have a `Course` table with columns `ID` (PK), `CourseID`, `CourseTitle`.

`textBook` table (all columns, `ID` (PK)) is a many to many relationship so multiple courses can have the same book and courses can also have multiple different books.

When I try to insert a new text book into my database using C# I get an error on my foreign key. The `Course` table is parent, `Textbook` table is child. The ID column in both tables is set to identity and auto increments. ID is my foreign key in my `textBook` table referencing the `Course` table.

here is my intermediate table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookCourse]
(
[cID] INT NOT NULL Unique, 
[BookID] INT NOT NULL Unique, 
[BookCourseID] INT NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_BookCourse] PRIMARY KEY ([BookCourseID]) 
)
```

here is my textBook table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[textBooks] (
[thirteenISBN]   VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
[CourseID]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[BookTitle]      VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[Ancillary]      VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[BookActive]     VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[ActiveDate]     VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[InactiveDate]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Author]         VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[Imprint]        VARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Publisher]      VARCHAR (100) NULL,
[EditionAndDate] VARCHAR (120) NULL,
[tenISBN]        VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[VendorISBN]     INT           NULL,
[ebookAvailable] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[eISBN]          VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[Notes]          VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[BookID]             INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_textBooks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookID] ASC), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_textBooks_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([BookID]) REFERENCES [BookCourse]([BookID])
);
```

Here is my Course Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course] (
[CourseID]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[CourseTitle] VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[cID]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Course] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([cID] ASC), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([cID]) REFERENCES [BookCourse]([cID]) 
);
```

Table Adapters with Insert:

```
JUTDMSTableAdapters.textBooksTableAdapter bookTableAdapter;
bookTableAdapter = new JUTDMSTableAdapters.textBooksTableAdapter();

JUTDMSTableAdapters.CourseTableAdapter courseTableAdapter;
courseTableAdapter = new JUTDMSTableAdapters.CourseTableAdapter();

courseTableAdapter.Insert( CourseID: txtCourseID.Text, CourseTitle: txtCourseTitle.Text);

bookTableAdapter.Insert( thirteenISBN: txt13ISBN.Text, CourseID: txtCourseID.Text, BookTitle: txtBookTitle.Text, Ancillary: txtAncillary.Text,
            BookActive: txtBookActive.Text, ActiveDate: txtActiveDate.Text, InactiveDate: txtInactiveDate.Text, Author: txtAuthor.Text,
            Imprint: txtImprint.Text, Publisher: txtPublisher.Text, EditionAndDate: txtEditionDate.Text,
            VendorISBN: vendISBN, tenISBN: txt10ISBN.Text, ebookAvailable: txtEBookAvailable.Text, eISBN: txtEISBN.Text, Notes: txtNotes.Text);
```

I figured in my `Course` table adapter insert I wouldn't have to add the cID column seeing as it is auto increment but I get this error:

> Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Course_ToTable". The conflict occurred in database "F:\HUTDMS V-2.0\HUTDMS V-2.0\APP_DATA\HUTDMS.MDF", table "dbo.BookCourse", column 'cID'.

BookID in the textbook table is autoincrement
cID in the Course table is autoincrement
BookCourseID in the BookCourse table is autoincrement.

Comment: Can you clarify the tables structure? Give the full create script of all relevant tables as the provided description is confusing.

Comment: I created the tables in visual studio in a local db using the design view. two tables, 1 has Course info, and the other is just book characteristics. (isbn, active date, inactive date, ebook available, etc...)

Comment: it does not matter where you created it. E.g. if you deployed your objects to SQL Server, you can easily script them by SSMS. From the information that you provided, the table design is incorrect. For many-to-many relationship you have to use three tables, Book table, Course table and then intermediate table - BookCourse table. You first add book into Book table, then Course into Course table, finally you add the pair (CourseID, BookID) into BookCourse table.

Comment: Does the value of ID you are trying to insert already exist in the Course table?  It just seems like a simple foreign key violation by trying to insert a value in a referencing column where the value doesn't already exist in the referenced column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many-to-many relationship you need to use three tables, Book table, Course table and then intermediate table - BookCourse table. Book table refers BookCourse, Course Table refers BookCourse. There are NOT direct references between Book and Course tables

You first add book into Book table, then Course into Course table, finally you add the pair (CourseID, BookID) into BookCourse table.

As for BookCourse table, you may add composite primary key (CourseID, BookID), or add identity key BookCourseID, but if latter then you need to make sure there are no duplicates - you can create an unique constraint.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: I've created the BookCourse Table and made a column of BookCourseID. I then changed the 'ID' Column in my book and course tables to BookCourseID. BookCourseID is my PK in all 3 tables and is set to identity so it auto increments but I still receive the same error on the foreign key?? I'm beyond confused. Thanks for your help it makes perfect sense

Comment: BookCourseID (PK) should be present only in BookCourse table. When you have a new course for 3 existing books (BookID = {1,2,3}, you insert first an entry to Course table (e.g. CourseID = 10), then three entries to BookCourse table (1,10), (2,10), (3,10). When you have a new book for 2 existing course (CourseID = {21,22}, you insert first an entry to Book table (e.g. BookID = 50), then two entries to BookCourse table (50,21), (50,22). There are only two references (Book <-> BookCourse) and (Course <-> BookCourse)

Comment: So If I understand you correctly here which I think I do, in my BookCourse Table, I should have BookCourseID(PK), BookID, CourseID. So then in my course table I have a course id and in my book table I have a book id then in my book table my foreign key is BookID? and course foreign key is CourseID? or do they have to reference  a primary key

Comment: BookCourse: BookCourseID(PK), BookID (FK), CourseID (FK).  Book: BookID (PK).  Course: CourseID (PK)    Both Course and Book tables do not have foreign keys. Only BookCourse has foreign keys.  Here is example: http://port.sas.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/233/mod_book/chapter/140/12%20Image%20D3.jpg

Comment: ok ive got that down! now for identity columns I think this might be whats giving me trouble here. I have my BookID as identity for auto increment, my courseID as identity for auto increment. Do I have to set those columns to identity in my BookCourse table as well?

Comment: No. Identity property for BookID should be only in Book table. Same for CourseID - only in Course table. Once you insert the new row to Book or Course table, you get the ID of that new record (you need to execute SCOPE_IDENTITY() just after the insert) and insert that new ID into BookCourse table together with other data

Comment: Just wondering, have you read ALL my comments + answer? If you ignore it, I'm exiting from this conversation.

Comment: Yes, I've been doing all you've said and sofar all makes sense Ive got everything set up and all makes sense I just have NO clue why I'm receiving the error on FK. I added all my table create statements so anyone can see if I've made a mistake along the way or if i'm missing an important part on my insert.

Comment: So why did you create FOREIGN KEYs in textbook and Course table if I told you not to do so? This is just one example. Really... it's not productive.

Comment: 100% missed that clicked right on the link and started getting to work, but after putting my FK's on my intermediate table, all works. Thank you so much sorry for the prolonged problem,

Comment: no worries. Note [dbo].[BookCourse] table has invalid unique constraint. Uniqueness should be applied to the pair of CourseID, BookID, not to the single IDs. [dbo].[Course] should not have cID, identity should be set to CourseID